# How to recognize remote control hold?

Tags: ios, swift, remote-control

Is there a way to recognize when the Apple Earphone Remote Control button is held, instead of initiating Voice Control? I mean, disable Voice Control and do something else instead when the button is long pressed?

I know it has already been asked in [How to receive single tap and hold Remote-Control Event with iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339492/how-to-receive-single-tap-and-hold-remote-control-event-with-ios), but this answer does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [UIEventType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIEventType) under [UIEventSubtype](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIEventSubtype) you will get these 4 events from Earbuds

```
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop
```

There is not any subevent defined related to Long press of the button.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But I wonder if there is another way to detect it. Even using Apple's Private API.